# Credit card processing with Quickbooks Payments API

Tags: php, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I've been trying for several days to find PHP sample code or a PHP-based SDK for [Quickbooks Payments API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_QuickBooks_Payments) to integrate credit card processing into an e-commerce site to no avail.

I have found the [Quickbooks Online API PHP SDK](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK) but it doesn't seem to handle the raw credit card processing I need, only a way to log general payments into Quickbooks Online.

Does anyone have an example of authentication, token generation, and subsequent credit card processing using PHP for Quickbooks Payments API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a library that does that (full disclaimer - I'm the author):

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Examples specific to payment processing:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/payments

A potential gotcha:

- I haven't implemented OAuth 2 yet (Intuit is in the process of migrating from OAuth 1 to OAuth 2) so if you're a new app, you might have to wait until I implement that (or you could do that and make a pull request!)

It's standard OAuth 2, there's nothing fancy about it. So you should really be able to grab any PHP OAuth 2 lib and implement this yourself as well. There are tons of OAuth 2 tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks! Your Quickbooks PHP DevKit looks awesome. As you mentioned, OAuth 2 will be important since my app is new and it's required.  I think you're right that it shouldn't be a major deal to swap out OAuth 1 with OAuth 2...let me see what I can do and if it looks straightforward, I'll make a pull request.

Comment: Just to confirm, does your SDK interface with the Payments API? Also, how to pass an access token and tokenized card? I'm referring to calls such as `$Payments = new QuickBooks_Payments($oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $sandbox);` and `$CreditCard = new QuickBooks_Payments_CreditCard($name, $number, $expyear, $expmonth, $street, $city, $region, $postalcode);` found [here](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/payments/example_creditcard_charge.php).

Comment: Our authorization code request (that precedes the request for access token) is requiring users to log in to their quickbooks account. We can't expect end-users to log in. How do we resolve this? Thank you